# Terraform lunch EC2 condition based on count

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Trying to lunch 1 or 2 instances based on a condition ( "single-target" )

**ERROR im getting :**

```
132:   target_id        = var.ec2-2
var.ec2-2 is empty tuple
Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required.
```

the use of that variable :

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "b" {
  target_id        = var.ec2-2

}
```

outputs :

```
output "ec2-2_ot" {
 value = aws_instance.ec2V2[*].id
 description = "the value of the network module ec2-2 id"
}
```

variable :

```
variable "single-target" {
  type=bool
  default=false
}
```

main.tf :

```
module "network_module" {
   ec2-2 = module.compute_module.ec2-2_ot
}
```

ec2 launch :

```
resource "aws_instance" "ec2V2" {
  count = var.single-target ? 0 : 1
  ami                         = var.ec2_ami
  instance_type               = var.ec2_type
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = var.key_pair
  vpc_security_group_ids = [ var.vpc-sg ]
  subnet_id = var.subnet-2
  user_data = file("PATH/user-data.sh")
          
  tags = {
    Name = var.ec2-2_name
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the count has been already set to the resource you are trying to create, the returning result list would need to be accessed via [Splat Expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/splat.html) mentioned in this terraform documentation.

If you need to choose specific index from the list of the result , then you can use the [element function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/element.html) to do so

So in your case, if you need to output EC2 id it would be as follows.

```
output "thisisoutput" {
       value = aws_instance.ec2V2[*].arn
}
```

Comment: hey !
changed it to look like you said , the problem is im using this output in another module : 
ec2-2 = module.compute_module.ec2-2_ot and now im getting :
The given value is not suitable for child module variable "ec2-2" defined at ... string required

Comment: Hi, would you mind opening up another question with the new issue. Since the question in this post has already been answered. If the issue is resolved as per the answer , feel free to accept the answer as well.